# Why isn't my code running?

Tags: unity, c#

I have other code that uses this same kind of format but for some reason this one is not working. Is there a specific reason why? It is connected to a game object and if I were to not use the if statement then it would work but I don't see why the if statement would be an issue.

The code is being used to close and open a Raw Image element that is nested within Canvas.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class Invetory : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("Q"))
            this.gameObject.active = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried pressing the `Q` key?

Comment: `Update` is not called on scripts on inactive game objects, so you can't use code inside `Update` to "turn on" that same object. Have you tried writing similar code to run on an object you do *not* set to inactive?

Comment: @DMGregory I have not, but even when I changed it to set the alpha transparency it still did not work. I also had it do a print("here") but it still didn't work. I have it set inside of a canvas, would that make a difference?

Comment: Is the canvas object or one of its parents set to inactive?

Comment: @DMGregory nope, it is a child to another canvas but it's active.

Comment: Canvas objects should not be nested. What you should do is edit your question to walk us through the steps to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. That is every step a reader would need to follow to make the simplest example of this problem, starting from a new, empty project. Once we can reproduce the exact issue, we can test solutions to be sure they'll work for you.

Comment: @DMGregory I'm sorry I meant it is a Raw Image nested inside of a Canvas. Also I explained the situation a little bit better, is that what you meant?

Comment: Could a reader use only the text of this post and, without asking any follow-up questions, reproduce an exact copy of your scene from scratch? If not, you are not done. Your code still shows an attempt to set `this.gameObject.active = true` which can only have an effect if `.active` had previously been false, in which case `Update` would not be called. You said you tried running the code on an object that was *not* inactive — show that version.

Comment: Another potential error can be if all your Game Objects are active that you set your project to use the other input system

Comment: Note too that when you use the string version of `GetKeyDown`, the letter keys are identified by lower-case letters ("q" not "Q") — [see the list of supported identifiers here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html). A better policy is to use `KeyCode.Q` — it saves you from common errors and processing overhead of "stringly typed" code.

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you, I did notice that and fixed it

Comment: If that solved your problem, you can post it as an answer below. If you still need help, make sure you edit your question as described above.

Answer (score 3):

[As DMGregory said](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/206332/why-isnt-my-code-running#comment376057_206332):

> when you use the string version of `GetKeyDown`, the letter keys are identified by lower-case letters ("q" not "Q") — [see the list of supported identifiers here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html).
>
> A better policy is to use `KeyCode.Q` — it saves you from common errors and processing overhead of "stringly typed" code.